# What kind of scores are returned by cross_validation.cross_val_score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I can't find this information in sci-kit learn documentation. But based on the numbers I got, it doesn't look like scores are mean squared error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cross_val_score` calls the `.score()` method of the estimator you pass in and what that returns varies depending on the estimator. You have to look into the documentation for each estimator to find out what the corresponding `.score()` method returns. You can override this default behaviour with the `scoring` parameter. This is documented [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics).

Comment: If different models return different score metrics, then how can we use it to do model selection?

Comment: all models within a family will use the same metric so there is no inconsistency. For example if you use RandomForestClassifier the `.score()` method will return the mean accuracy. With `cross_val_score` you are comparing one RandomForestClassifier model with some hyperparameters to another with different hyperparameters and selecting the best.

Answer (score 1):

I avoided this problem by first calculating predicted values with cross_val_predict and then using the predicted values with y_test to get score with metrics.accuracy_score.

```
# Function that runs the requested algorithm and returns the accuracy metrics
def fit_ml_algo(algo, X_train, y_train, cv):

# One Pass
model = algo.fit(X_train, y_train)
acc = round(model.score(X_train, y_train) * 100, 2)

# Cross Validation 
train_pred = model_selection.cross_val_predict(algo, 
                                              X_train, 
                                              y_train, 
                                              cv=cv, 
                                              n_jobs = -1)
# Cross-validation accuracy metric
acc_cv = round(metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, train_pred) * 100, 2)

return train_pred, acc, acc_cv
```